# Do numbers $a, b, c$ exist such that there is always a polynomial with integer roots?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, roots

Is it possible for some numbers $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$, $abc \neq 0$ that for every $n > 3$, there exists a polynomial $P_n(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x + ... + ax^2 + bx 
+ c$ such that all its roots are integers?

I have concluded with Vieta's formula that all coefficients of every polynomial $P_n$ must be integers.

Comment: Any integer root would have to be a divisor of $c$, so the factored form of the polynomials is pretty limited.

Comment: Yeah,  I just realized that.

Comment: @lulu Yes, up to a point. There can be multiple 1s and -1s as roots of P and I don't know how to use this info.

Comment: I'd start with $c=p$, a prime.  So the only candidates are $(x+1)^r(x-1)^s(x\pm p)$.  See how restrictive that is as to the possible $a,b$.

Comment: Where do you find these problems ? they are amazing

Comment: @MohammedM.Zerrak From some old book, that is, unfortunately not available online nor in English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope.

Let's say the polynomial has $N$ integer roots $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_N \in \{ -1, 1 \}$ and $M$ integer roots $\lambda_{N+1},\ldots,\lambda_{N+M} \notin \{ -1, 1 \}$. Upto a sign, we have

$$\prod_{k=1}^M \lambda_{k+N} = \pm \prod_{k=1}^{N+M} \lambda_k = \pm c$$

So $M$ is bounded from above by  $\Omega(c)$, the number of prime factors in $n$ (see wiki entry of [prime omega function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function) for definition/detail).

By [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas), $N$ is also bounded.

$$N = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{\lambda_k^2} \le \sum_{k=1}^{N+M}\frac{1}{\lambda_k^2} = \frac{b^2 - 2ac}{c^2}$$

In order for such a polynomial to have all integer roots, its degree need to satisfy
$$n = N + M \le \frac{b^2-2ac}{c^2} + \Omega(c)$$